# query properties of numpy dtypes

Tags: python, numpy

I have a program which uses at runtime some [numpy datatypes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) e.g. `uint8`, `int8`, `uint16`, `int16`, `uint32`, `int32`.

Is there a way at run time to query these datatype objects and determine the following properties?

- their minimum value
- their maximum value
- whether they are signed
- the size in bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ints you could use [`iinfo`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.iinfo.html) to get part of the way to what you want:

```
d = np.dtype('int8')  # for example

min_value = np.iinfo(d).min
max_value = np.iinfo(d).max
signed = min_value!=0   # can also use "dtype.kind", see Jaime's comment
size = d.itemsize       # see comment
```

Comment: For the last two, `np.dtype(np.uint8).kind` returns `u` (and `np.dtype(np.int8).kind` returns `i`). You also have `np.dtype(np.uint8).itemsize` which return 1.

Comment: @Jaime: Thanks for the suggestions, and I incorporated your suggestions into my answer.  I left the min_value!=0 since that seemed more obvious to me and there weren't so many `kind` cases to worry about, but if there's an issue with that, let me know and I'll change it again.

Comment: cool, thanks! link to the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.iinfo.html) and I'll accept.